# Sharepoint 2016 configuration error

Tags: sharepoint

I have a SharePoint project, I have installed SharePoint 2016 and set up a single-server-farm, so my problem is when I open SharePoint 2016 central administration then keying in the user name and password for me to access the central admin, I get this error, any solution?[SharePoint error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fyt4.png)

Comment: have you checked the ULS logs? you could be getting that error for multiple reasons.

Answer (score 1):

nThe information you are providing is very little, but here are two ways to troubleshoot this problem:

OPTION 1) You can check ULS logs to find more information, ULS Logs are located at:
C:\Program files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\LOGS

OPTION 2) You can open up the IIS (Internet Information Services) and check to see if the application pools are running, if they are running, proceed to check the status of the Sites, in this case you need to check the Central Admin V4.